# API for Google translate app like feature for website

Tags: javascript, google-api, ocr, image-recognition

Is there any API for Google translate app like feature for website in which user upload an image and start selecting image textual area and he/she get the text?

I found google vision API but its not just what i want. I want that image should be showing on website and user is selecting textual part of the image with mouse and user is getting the same text in some variable so that he/she can print the text wherever required.

Comment: Please don't add the image-to-text tag. That's what OCR means so at best it should be a synonym, not a separate tag.